# Is it possible to install Ubuntu on a PC which shows 'disk repair' while on Windows 8 without losing data?

Tags: system-installation, disk

My laptop was running Windows 8, but recently it shows disk repair on start, and it goes on for ever. I would like to move to Ubuntu OS.

Is it possible to install Ubuntu in this condition without losing data?

Comment: it will take a long time for disk repair. it has to complete to see if any data ws recoverble ....  this is an indication that the drive might be failing.

Comment: Is it possible to install Ubuntu at this stage?

Comment: you can, but you will have to wipe the drive unless you already have free space on it. NOTE: disk repair on boot is an indication that the drive is failing

Comment: If you boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and start the `Disks` application, what does the `SMART Data & Tests` have to say about the drive? Boot to a Windows install/repair disc and see if you can repair your C: drive. And no, don't try and install Ubuntu on a drive that has a problem.

Answer (score 3):

One thing you need to do will allow you to do this without difficulty:

- Create a backup of your personal data.

As always: We all know it is easy to remove a file you did not want to remove. Or about virusses and crypolockers. So you already got one.
When you have a backup and are sure you can restore the backup you can do with your system what you want and put the files back onto the system.

If you do not ... try with a Live ubuntu session. If you can backup from there you are save to go too.

Mind that it is not a good idea to use NTFS when you do not have a Windows operating system. Fixing issues with NTFS formatted disks is best done on Windows. Yes, we have tools but those never will have 100% guarantee to work perfectly.

> but recently it shows disk repair on start, and it goes on for ever.

The 1st means your disk is failing. The 2nd is highly dependent on your system but it always takes long.

The 1st also means you might have trouble installing Ubuntu: hardware problems don't go away by installing another operating system.

---

Installing Ubuntu on a system that is fully used by Windows WILL delete C:, D: and any other driveletter unless you manually tell it not to remove a partition. You can keep D: (E: etc) but be really careful not to mark that partition for formatting. There is no way back if you do.

Comment: if windows is booting to disk repair, he can not back up his data. the drive will show as unreadable.

Comment: @avery reworded it :)

Comment: I too think that is the case!

Comment: So, is there any way to overcome the situation? I kept the pc running for more than 12 hours with 'disk repair'!

Comment: if I was you I would get  a new disk. Install an OS onto that and add the 2nd disk to your system and then try to get the data of that disk.

Comment: Could you please explain how I can do that?

Comment: Pick any generic installation guide you find with google ;)

Comment: Google for: `replace hard drive <exact name of your laptop>` - after success  use an external USB to SATA adapter to be able to plug in your presumable broken drive as an external USB drive for data rescue.